# LED doesn't turn off as intended in sound sensor circuit

Tags: led, resistors, arduino-uno

I am using a sound sensor and would like that when sound is detected by the sensor, an external LED also reacts to the sound and flickers to the sound.

The connections for the LED is the positive pin to a 200 ohm resistor then to pin 11 on the Arduino Uno and the negative pin goes to the GND pin of the Arduino. When I run the sound sensor works as intended, but the LED stays on at all time.

This is the code I'm using:

```cpp
const int ledpin=11; 
const int soundpin=A2;
const int threshold=200;
void setup()
 {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
pinMode(soundpin,INPUT);
}
void loop() {
      // reads analog data from sound sensor
int soundsens=analogRead(soundpin);
if (soundsens>=threshold) //turns led on
{
digitalWrite(ledpin,HIGH); 
delay(1000);
}
else{
digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW);
}
}
```

Comment: Mari81 - Welcome :-) Please [edit] your question and add more detail e.g. how do you know that the value of `threshold` is correct for your hardware? Can you also add a photo of your hardware? Also add details of the sound sensor and ideally its schematic too. Have you got a multimeter or oscilloscope to measure the output voltage from your sound sensor? If so, please add the measured voltages when "enough" sound is present (and when it isn't) into your question. Thanks.

Comment: what is the actual value of `soundsens` when sound is not detected?

Comment: I think the problem may lie with the line **const int soundpin=A2;** A2 is not an integer therefore soundpin is undefined so you won't read anything. Did you mean 12 instead?

Comment: In addition to not adding a 1s delay, also print out the value of Soundsense to see what's really going on. You can print this to the Serial Monitor

Comment: @SamGibson HI this is small at home project, I unfortunately don't have access to any voltage measuring devices. I'm very new to coding and most of these components. I will add more detail to future questions apologies. I will edit my question to add more detail to it thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a 1 second delay after the volume has reached your specified threshold. This means any noise detected above the threshold, will activate the LED for 1 second. after it exists the conditional, it could easily be thrown back into the conditional again, thereby holding the LED on for another second.
This must be why it appeared that LED was staying on forever.

Updated code:

```cpp
const int ledpin=11; 
const int soundpin=A2;
const int threshold=200;

void setup()
 {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(soundpin,INPUT);
}
void loop() {
    // reads analog data from sound sensor
    int soundsens=analogRead(soundpin);
    if (soundsens>=threshold) //turns led on
    {
        digitalWrite(ledpin,HIGH); 
    }
    else{
        digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW);
    }
    delay(2);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Mari81, note how easy it is to read the correctly indented code compared with what you posted in your question. You can edit your question to fix it.